# CakePHP Access Page Without Login In

Tags: authentication, cakephp

So, I'm learning CakePHP and I'm doing that Bookmarker Tutorial. I'm in the Login part and it's working. In this tutorial when you add Login you'are kicked to the login page(localhost/users/login) everytime you try to access some other page.

I want to know how can I let the users access an specific page without login in.

Comment: add $this->Auth->allow(['functionName']); in initialize function [initialize controller function] (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/part-two.html#adding-logout)

Comment: You can also use [TinyAuth](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth) and just whitelist the actions in a simple INI file, no need for any code modifications.

Answer (score 5):

Refer to the manual: [Making Actions Public](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public)

> There are often times controller actions that you wish to remain entirely public or that don’t require users to be logged in.
>
> **AuthComponent** is pessimistic and defaults to denying access.
>
> You can mark actions as public actions by using **AuthComponent::allow()**. By marking actions as public, AuthComponent will not check for a logged in user nor will authorize objects be checked:

```
// Allow only the view and index actions.
$this->Auth->allow(['view', 'index']);
```

Even in the [Bookmarker Tutorial AppController](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/part-two.html#adding-login) , you need to focus on this portion:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
   
    /* Other code */

    $this->Auth->allow(['display']); // Allows the display page without loggin in. 

    $this->Auth->allow(['display', 'function1', 'function2']); // This will let you access display, function1, function 2 without logging in.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp Uses Auth Component and by default all the actions defined except the login function are allowed to the logged in users only.

So, you can use

```
<?php // replace function1 and function2 below with your function names 
 $this->Auth->allow(array('function1', 'function2')); ?>
```

in your beforeFilter function in the controller. This will allow you to access the functions defined in this array for this particular controller without the login/Authentication.